Freezing-Point Depression and Boiling- Point Elevation diagram

Hey I don't understand how can it be that the phase diagram of the solvent in a solution, can be separated from of the overall solution? isn't the freezing or melting and etc is of the whole solution? (for example if the solution freeze isn't it as a whole and not only the solvent?)
This is what I was given:
Given that The red curves the solvent in a solution.
and the blue curves represent phase diagram for a pure solvent.
it is mentioned also that:" Two assumptions are implicit
One is that the solute is nonvolatile, the other is that the solid that freezes from a solution is pure solvent. For many mixtures, these requirements
are easily met.*"

And what is the problem? Molecules/ions of solutes seldom fit into the matrix of the solid solvent. With exceptions of occlusion when they are mechanically trapped, they remain is solution, unless the solution gets saturated and they precipitate. Chemical potential of solvent in solution is decreased, what leads to the solid solvent reaching its value at lower melting point, while vapor pressure reaches external pressure at higher boiling point.
